# Keep and display product custom field value in WooCommerce Admin Order pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, custom-fields

I created some code to display the stock availability on woocommerce>>orders. see pics (specialnotering).

The problem is that if I change custom field text then all previous order is updated with new custom field text.

For example: one customer confirmed an order for a product on January 2021 where custom field text was "Product will be available on March 2021". 2nd customer confirmed the same product order on march 2021 where new custom field text is "Product will be available on May 2021".

Both order is showing the last custom field text "Product will be available on May 2021".

I want to display the old order with old custom field text and new order with new custom field text. If any body can solve it or can give me some idea, it will help full for me.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'display_order_data_in_admin' );
function display_order_data_in_admin( $order ){
    ?>
    <h4><?php _e( 'Speciellnotering', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h4>
    <?php

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        //fetch text from custom_field
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $availability = $product->get_availability();
        $quantity = $item->get_quantity();

        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
        $sku = get_post_meta( $variation_id, '_sku', true );
        $custom_text_message = get_post_meta( $variation_id, 'custom_field', true );

        if($product->is_type('variable')){
            if($custom_text_message && $quantity<=-1){
                $availability['availability'] = $custom_text_message;
            }elseif(!$custom_text_message && $quantity<=-1){
                $availability['availability'] = __('Right now is not available', 'woocommerce');
            }else{
                $availability['availability'] =__('Finns i lager', 'woocommerce');
            }
            ?>
            <?php  echo __( 'Artnr' ).' ('.$sku.')' .': '.$availability['availability'].'<br>';

        //for simple product
        }else{
            $product = $item->get_product();
            $sku=$product->get_sku();
            $availability = $product->get_availability();
            $custom_stock_message=get_post_meta( $product_id, 'custom_stock_message', true );
            $quantity = $item->get_quantity();

            if($product->is_type('simple')){
                if($custom_stock_message && $quantity<=0){
                    $availability['availability'] = $custom_stock_message;
                }elseif(!$custom_stock_message && $quantity<=0){
                    $availability['availability'] = __('Right now is not available', 'woocommerce');
                }else{
                    $availability['availability'] =__('Finns i lager', 'woocommerce');
                }
            }
            ?>
            <?php echo __( 'Artnr' ).' ('.$sku.')' .': '.$availability['availability'].'<br>';
        }
    }?>
    <?php
}
```

[image: Click to view pics]

Comment: You store this custom text on the product or the product variation, so what did you _expect_ to happen then? If you want something specific to a particular item in a particular order - well then store it _on_ that item then.

Comment: how can I store custom text on product or in a particular item? can you write sample code then it will easy to understand for me.

Comment: In your code you are using `$quantity = $item->get_quantity();` which value is always **up to 1 *(higher than zero)***, so `$quantity<=-1`or `$quantity<=0` will always be false… It means that in your IF / ELSE statements you will always fall on the ELSE part.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, problem is not with if else logic....logic is working good and getting my expected output. But problem that already described is when I change the custom field's text if necessary then it affects with all (new+old) orders.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

Instead you should first save your product custom fields as custom order item meta data, to avoid changes when your product custom field changes.

I have simplified, and optimized your initial code. Also `$item->get_quantity()` value is always higher than zero. So in the code below I use the product stock quantity instead:

```
// Save product custom availiability text as custom hidden order item meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_custom_image_id_to_order_item', 10, 4 );
function save_custom_image_id_to_order_item( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();

    // Product variation type
    if ( $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ) {
        $availability = $product->get_meta('custom_field');
    }
    // Other product types
    else {
        $availability = $product->get_meta('custom_stock_message');
    }

    if ( empty($availability) ) {
        // save as hidden order item meta data
        $item->update_meta_data('_availability', array($availability) );
    }
}

// Display order item availability in admin orders
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'display_order_item_availability_in_admin_orders' );
function display_order_item_availability_in_admin_orders( $order ){
    echo '<h4>' . __( 'Speciellnotering', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product      = $item->get_product();
        $quantity     = $item->get_quantity();

        $stock_qty    = $product->get_stock_quantity();
        $sku          = $product->get_sku();

        $availability = $item->get_meta('_availability'); // Get order item custom field
        $availability = reset($availability); // Convert array to string

        if ( $stock_qty < 0 ) {
            if ( empty($availability) ) {
                $availability = __('Inte tillgänglig just nu', 'woocommerce');
            }
        } else {
            $availability = __('Finns i lager', 'woocommerce');
        }
        echo __('Artnr', 'woocommerce') . ' (' . $sku . ')' . ': ' . $availability . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec, but I change custom field/custom stock message then still display the new text with all order. I don't have problem with 'Inte tillgänglig just nu' and 'Finns i lager' condition. I have problem with custom field(variable product) and custom stock message(simple product). I always modify this 2 field according to suppliers information. when I modify text on march 2021, it affects the all order that was made before March. I want modified text will effect all order that will make after March and all order before March will be unchanged. Thanks in advance